# PostgreSQL: Create schema in specific database

Tags: sql, database, schema, postgresql

I need to write an **sql script** that creates both a **new database *AND* a new schema** in the database I just created.

How can I do it? Can I somehow change the current database to the new one? Or can I somehow specify the database for CREATE SCHEMA?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.0

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You can connect to the database, and execute the "CREATE SCHEMA" statement. That should result in a new schema in that database. It's not as tough as you think ;)  When you want to do this from a .SQL file instead, you can use the \connect command as such:

```
 CREATE DATABASE foo;
 \connect foo;
 CREATE SCHEMA yourschema;
```

Comment: I know that. But how can I do it in the same SQL file as the one that created the database with CREATE DATABASE?

Comment: @Axel: You connect to the database.  Don't know how?  Simple do a `pg_dumpall` and read how it does it.  Or use \connect.  Whichever.

Comment: @Seth Robertson Can you provide an example in an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @Axel Fontaine Ah, sorry, that wasn't really clear from your question. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Bear in mind that `\connect` is a command specific to [`psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html). Trying to execute an SQL script containing such command in another client (e.g. pgAdmin3) will not work.

Comment: @Millen A. Radev That is very true. However, since his question is tagged with "psql", I'm doubting that is going to be an issue. But yes, \connect is psql specific.

Comment: The OP has added the `psql` tag after my comment.

Answer (score 4):

Login to New-Database with new user:

```
postgres=> \connect newdb user1
...
You are now connected to database "newdb" as user "user1".
newdb=>
```

To create schema with new user "user1" in newdb:

```
newdb=> CREATE SCHEMA s1;
```

To list the schema :

```
SELECT * from information_schema.schemata;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create database using
--CREATE DATABASE test;

Enter to the test database using
--psql -d test;

Create your schema in test database using
--create schema if not exists test_schema;