# Create New Database and a Schema in new database using Sql Script in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a new database and a schema in the new database using Sql script as below. The database is PostgreSql 14.1

```
    DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS DEZDAZ;
    
    CREATE DATABASE DEZDAZ
        WITH 
        OWNER = postgres
        ENCODING = 'UTF8'
        TABLESPACE = pg_default
        CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
      
        \connect DEZDAZ;

        CREATE SCHEMA DEZDAZ;
```

Keep getting below error:

```
DROP DATABASE
CREATE DATABASE
error: \connect: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  database "DEZDAZ" does not exist
```

I have followed the answer below:
[PostgreSQL: Create schema in specific database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508267/postgresql-create-schema-in-specific-database)

Thanks for  your help.

Comment: Try `\connect dezdaz`. You did not do `CREATE DATABASE "DEZDAZ"` so the database name is folded to lower case `dezdaz` per [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) Looks like `\connect` is doing `"DEZDAZ"` and not finding the upper case version of the name.

Comment: that was it @Adrian Klaver. Please post it as answer, will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

`\connect dezdaz`.

You did not do `CREATE DATABASE "DEZDAZ"` so the database name is folded to lower case `dezdaz` per [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS). Looks like `\connect` is doing `"DEZDAZ"` and not finding the upper case version of the name. This is called out in `src/bin/psql/command.c`:

```
/*
 * Read and interpret an argument to the \connect slash command.
...

/*
         * Ideally we should treat the arguments as SQL identifiers.  But for
         * backwards compatibility with 7.2 and older pg_dump files, we have to
         * take unquoted arguments verbatim (don't downcase them). For now,
         * double-quoted arguments may be stripped of double quotes (as if SQL
         * identifiers).  By 7.4 or so, pg_dump files can be expected to
         * double-quote all mixed-case \connect arguments, and then we can get rid
         * of OT_SQLIDHACK.
         */
```