# How to create a schema in a specific database using bash script?

Tags: sql, postgresql, bash

How to create the schema 'testschema' in the database 'testdb' using bash script?

The database is running in a docker container.
I've created a bash script that has following lines:
DB_NAME='testdb'
schm='testschema'

```
PGPASSWORD=$PGPASS psql -X -h localhost -p $DB_PORT -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE $DB_NAME;"
PGPASSWORD=$PGPASS psql -X -h localhost -p $DB_PORT -U postgres -c "CREATE SCHEMA $schm;"
```

After executing this it will create a schema but in postgres db. That is not what I want.

If I add a db name then it produces an error:

```
PGPASSWORD=$PGPASS psql -X -h localhost -p $DB_PORT -U postgres -c "CREATE SCHEMA $DB_NAME.$schm;"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508267/postgresql-create-schema-in-specific-database might be helpful

Comment: Add a `-d $DB_NAME` switch to your `psql` calls, after creating this database. The thread linked above does mention this but in the last, least upvoted answer.

Comment: I've already tried the solutions from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508267/postgresql-create-schema-in-specific-database. That doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `-d $DB_NAME` switch to your `psql` calls, after creating this database.

```bash
PGPASSWORD=$PGPASS psql -X -h localhost -p $DB_PORT -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE $DB_NAME;"
PGPASSWORD=$PGPASS psql -X -h localhost -p $DB_PORT -U postgres -d $DB_NAME -c "CREATE SCHEMA $schm;"
```

Without specifying the database `psql` defaults to `postgres`.
From `man psql`:

> `-d dbname`
>
> `--dbname=dbname`
>
> Specifies the name of the database to connect to. This is equivalent to specifying dbname as the first non-option argument on the command line. The dbname can be a connection string. If so, connection string parameters will override any conflicting command line options.